# Relation between a group's cardinality and number of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why  are  these  following  situations  not  possible?

A.  An  infinite  group  has  finite  number  of  subgroups

B.  An  uncountable  group  has  countable  number  of  subgroups.

Any  infinite  group  that  I  can  think  of  now  has infinite  number  of  subgroups.But  what  is  the  logic  behind  it ?And  why  the  number  has  to  be  uncountable  if  the  group  is  uncountable?

Comment: For the uncountable case, note that any element of the group generates a (cyclic) subgroup which is finite or countably infinite.

Comment: In fact if $G$ is infinite, there are precisely $|G|$ cyclic subgroups.

Comment: Question A. is old - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413154/a-group-that-has-a-finite-number-of-subgroups-is-finite?rq=1). Question B is similar to A.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909385/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyclic groups to the rescue!

If an infinite group has an element of infinite order (that is, a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$) then it has an infinite number of subgroups (because $\Bbb Z$ does).

Otherwise, every element is of finite order, in which case, if we only have a finite number of subgroups $G = \bigcup\limits_k \langle g_{i_k}\rangle$, which is finite, contradiction.

The uncountable case is similar, a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Answer (score 4):

Say $G$ is infinite. Let $S(x)$ denote the subgroup generated by $x\in G$. If there exists $x$ such that $S(x)$ is infinite then $G$ has infinitely many subgroups, since an infinite cyclic group has infinitely many subgroups. On the other hand if every $S(x)$ is finite then there must be infinitely many distinct subgroups of the form $S(x)$, since $G=\bigcup_{x\in G}S(x)$.

If $G$ is uncountable a simpler argument works; every $S(x)$ is at most countable, so there must be uncountably many distinct $S(x)$.